# Predefined Form Fields from database

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am creating an online bank. On login, it created a session for that user. The user than has options to click on different transaction types.So when the user clicks on open an account button, it will go to openAccount.jsp page. I also have a form with a users first name, last name, and email in the openAccount.jsp. When the user clicks on the open account button and is redirected to the openAccount.jsp, I want the form to be prefilled from the database based. I am not sure how? Here is my code so far:

home-page.jsp

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <form name = "OpenAccount" action="open-account.jsp" id="openaccount">
            <p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Open Account</button>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

open-account.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Open Account</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Please fill in the details</h3> 

    <form name="predifinedFields">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value= <%= request.getAttribute("firstname") %> > <br/><br/>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value= <%= request.getAttribute("lastname") %>> <br/><br/>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" value= <%= request.getAttribute("email") %>>  <br/><br/>
    </form>

    <form name="openAccount" action="OpenAccount" method="POST">
        Select the type of account: 
        <select name="accounttype">
            <option>Checking</option>
            <option>Saving</option>
        </select> <br/><br/>

        Initial Deposit: $<input type="text" name="deposit">  <br/><br/>

        Please check the box if everything above is complete:
        Agree <input type="radio" name="agree" value="Agree">
        Disagree <input type="radio" name="agree" value="Disagree">

        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

OpenAccount.java

```
public class OpenAccount extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {   
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {   
        String username = "";

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if(session != null)
        {
            username = (String) session.getAttribute("username");

            Users users = new Users();
            users = DBConnection.getUsers(username);

            request.setAttribute("firstname", users.getFirstName());
            request.setAttribute("lastname", users.getLastName());
            request.setAttribute("email", users.getEmail());
            //request.setAttribute("username", users.getUsername());
        }

        //  String firstName = (String) request.getParameter("firstname");
        //  String lastname = (String) request.getParameter("lastname");
        String email = (String) request.getParameter("email");
        String accountType = (String) request.getParameter("accounttype");
        String accept = (String) request.getParameter("agree");
        String deposit = (String) request.getParameter("deposit");

        if(accept.equals("Agree"))
        {
            if(accountType.equals("Checking"))
            {
                DBConnection.newCheckingAccount(email, deposit);
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("home-page.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }
            else if(accountType.equals("Saving"))
            {
                DBConnection.newSavingAccount(email, deposit);
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("home-page.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please modify the changes");
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("open-account.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }

    }
}
```

Database.java

```
public static Users getUsers(String username) 
    {
        Users user = new Users();
        try
        {
            DBConnection.connectToDB();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM userlogin where username=?";

            stmt = DBConnection.conn.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setString(1,username);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
                user.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
                user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return user;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case (basic servlet), you should follow this logic :

->browser 
->servlet which loads and prepares required data from database into request attributes as you have done and finally forwards to `open-account.jsp` 
 
->`open-account.jsp` use request attributes to render dynamically fields with your data retrieved from your database.

For other use cases, try to keep this simple logic :
->browser 
->servlet processing ....
->jsp rendering ....

Your form in `home-page.jsp` should post to the servlet (controller) :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <form name = "OpenAccount" action="/OpenAccount" id="openaccount">
            <p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Open Account</button>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

You should rename `OpenAccount` to `OpenAccountServlet` (keeping conventions is better) and configure correctly the `servlet` of `OpenAccountServlet` in your `web.xml` (or with annotations).
If you use `web.xml` file for the servlet configuration, the url posted in the previous `jsp` (`action="/OpenAccount"`) should match with the value in  `<url-pattern>/OpenAccount</url-pattern>`

The forward should do like that :

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("yourRequiredPath/open-account.jsp ").forward(request, response);
```